# Git : commit collision and commit rollback

Tags: git, collision

1. When I request log:

> MacBook-Pro-nnuttertools:program $ git log

I receive:

```
commit f2504e036044... (HEAD -> master, f2504e036044...)

Author: Nnuttertools <nnuttertools@gmail.com>

Date:   Mon Apr 29 00:12:00 2019 +0300

    CommitName
```

2.Then I want to save the state in the stash and switch to the commit:

> MacBook-Pro-nnuttertools:program $ git stash
>
> MacBook-Pro-nnuttertools:program $ git checkout f2504e036044...

But the first command throw an error:

```
warning: refname 'f2504e036044...' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git checkout -b $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
```

And the code is not restored. But older commits can do this.
What do I need to use to resolve collisions? I don’t have time to figure it out, unfortunately.The main goal now is to return the correct code)

Comment: Is the `git checkout` important to your question? If I understand correctly, `git stash` causes the error, correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes, because I can't return my true commit using `git checkout` .The commit I get is not the one I saved.

Comment: So which command causes the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, after the answer below, I don't have the error, but and after `git checkout` there are no changes.As if the last state of the code replaces the commit.

Comment: Which branch did you checkout?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice,
`commit f2504e... (HEAD -> newBranch, checkout)
Author: nnuttertools <nnuttertools@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 29 00:12:00 2019 +0300

    correct work with functions`


This is the log;
When I checkout f2504e... , I get a commit with a different date.
It's closer to this commit:


`commit c61ab8...
Author: nnuttertools <nnuttertools@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 26 15:00:22 2019 +0300

    ALL OK`

Comment: You can always do `git log` to see details about the most recent commits. Often I prefer `git log --oneline --graph` to get a nice graphical view of the commit history. Also, you seem to have created a branch named `checkout ` now. That doesn't seem like a good branch name to me.

Answer (score 4):

What you've done here is create a branch with the same name as an object. Git usually assumes that a 40-character hex name is an object ID, but in this case it's also a branch. It's confused, and so it told you that what you asked for was ambiguous.

The easiest solution is to temporarily check out a different branch, then delete the oddly named branch, and then check out the revision you want. So something like the following:

```
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git branch -D LONG-HEX-NAME
$ git branch checkout LONG-HEX-NAME
$ git branch -D temp
```

Comment: Much easier, going on the given logs: `git checkout master; git branch -d thatlongname`.